# Laravel - redirect request to external url and return its response as response

Tags: php, laravel, api

i'm building an app using Laravel for providing some API for an android application, and i'm using some external APIs from another server (with another URL). i want to make something like proxy or tunnel for external API requests from android side but in my own URL.

for example:
android wants to request for **externalUrl.com/api/objects** but i want he request to this **myDOmain.com/api/x/objects** and get the exact same response that the first link returns, without any change.
and there is more than one external API, and i don't want to write separate code for each one.

need something like this :

```
Route::any('/x/{somewhere}', function($request){
return [$request, externalUrl.com/api/{somewhere}]->response;
})
```

---

i'm not asking for http request libraries! i want to redirect request to another domain and return its request.

Comment: Have you looked into cURL?

Comment: @LLJ97 how should i use it for this purpose?

Comment: You can use cURL (the "pure" php implementation or a library like Guzzle) to make the request to the external url, take the response and send that as the response of your own api. Is that what you ask for or am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 2):

Best option is to install Guzzle. https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

It's really simple to use it.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'externalUrl.com/api/{somewhere}');

return $response->getBody();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guzzle :

```php
use Guzzle\Http\Client;
use Guzzle\Stream\PhpStreamRequestFactory;
[...]
$request = new Client("externalUrl.com/api/{$somewhere}");

$response = $request->send();
return $response->getBody();
```